# Wanted pages on my MediaWiki is not working How do i fix this?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api

So I have been working on my wiki for a while now and I wanted to check if there are any links that I have missed making. So I clicked on the wanted pages page but there are no links I found this surprising. So I made 10 new pages all with a few Lorim Ipsum text paragraphs and then a link to the same uncreated page. I did this with multiple links so that I could have multiple results. But I get none at all.
**The only thing it displays is:**

List of non-existing pages with the most links to them, excluding pages which only have redirects linking to them. For a list of non-existent pages that have redirects linking to them, see the list of broken redirects.

The following data is cached and may not be up to date. A maximum of 1,000 results are available in the cache.

There are no results for this report.

---

So that is a problem What I would want is for the page to work and show every link that is missing. So not just when multiple of the same link is missing. But when there is any missing red link.

how would I go about fixing/doing this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you should run [`maintenance/updateSpecialPages.php`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:UpdateSpecialPages.php). Usually, a cron job is created for this.